# Two Circles intersecting, common tangent: Proof $GI=IH$

Tags: geometry

I have the following problem:
Two circles (middle points $A,C$) have two intersections: $E,F$. Now we draw a common tangent on the circles and we'll get $G,H$. Let $I:=GH \cap EF$. Now I have to proof $GI=IH$.

I made this drawing:

[image]

and I tried to find some common angles or sides to use congruences, but I wasn't able to find some, because I have differnt circles with different radius'.

Perhaps someone can give me a hint how to move on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want an "analytical" approach, I would take a gander at this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately I'm looking for a proof with triangles, congruences and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $I$ is on the power line (also called radical axis) of the circles $(A)$ and $(C)$ its power with respect to each of the circles is the same. Thus, $IG^2 = IH^2\implies IG=IH$

**EDIT:** Without knowledge of the properties of radical axis, we can do the following. Show that triangles $\Delta IGE$ and $\Delta IFG$ are similar using the fact that $\angle IGE = \angle IFG$. Therefore, $\frac{IG}{IF}=\frac{IE}{IG}$ or equivalently $IG^2 =IE\cdot IF$. Similarly, we can show $IH^2=IE\cdot IF$ and the problem is solved.

Comment: I think the OP's question is equivalent to proving the common secant IF is the radical axis of $\,A\,,\,C\,$ ...

Comment: excellent! I got it.