# Two circles with a common tangent

Tags: geometry, circles, angle, tangent-line

Find the angle $\angle BAC$  in the following picture .

[image]

**My attempt :** I tried to apply the relationships in the both circles between different angles and arcs in many ways but it didn't work . Also joining the point $A$ , $E$ and the line $d$  didn't help (Note that if the intersection point of the $AE$ and the line $d$ is $D$ then $BD = DC$)

Comment: Why do you think $BD=DC$? Which intersection point $D$ do you have in mind?

Comment: @user376343 See this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433236/two-circles-intersecting-common-tangent-proof-gi-ih

Comment: The point where $AE$ cuts $d$? Please write it in your question.

Comment: @user376343 Thanks , I edited it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\angle BAE = \angle EBC$ because they both correspond to the circular arc $\overset{\frown}{BE}$

Similarly, $\angle CAE = \overset{\frown}{CE} = \angle ECB$

[image]

Now, the total internal angle of $\triangle ABC$ consists of\begin{align}
180^{\circ} &= \color{magenta}{\angle BAC} + 30^{\circ} + \angle EBC + \angle ECB + 40^{\circ} \\
&= \color{magenta}{\angle BAC} + 30^{\circ} + \color{magenta}{\big(}\angle BAE + \angle CAE\color{magenta}{\big)} + 40^{\circ} \\
&= \color{magenta}{2\angle BAC} + 30^{\circ} + 40^{\circ} 
\end{align}
Thus the desired $\displaystyle\angle BAC = \frac{180^{\circ} - 30^{\circ} - 40^{\circ}}2 = 55^{\circ}$

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot.