# Does the common chord of two circles pass through this point

Tags: geometry, circles, recreational-mathematics, conic-sections

Well, the question  is : Does the common chord of two circles pass through the  mid-point of the direct common tangent ?

my approach :
I tried to us power of a point with respect to a circle, some geometry and some other random attempts but could not get a good breakthrough at this question .

So, is the given statement true, kindly provide a counter example if its not true.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

$$PQ^2=PA\cdot PB = PS^2\to PQ=PS$$

Comment: [+1]  I appreciate your neat answers.

Comment: Same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433236/two-circles-intersecting-common-tangent-proof-gi-ih) but its answer isn't expressed in terms of power of a point.

Comment: @Raffaele Clipped from your picture  showing relevance of radical axis, Hope OK.

Answer (score 1):

The line you are talking about has also got other mathematical significance and a beautiful name too. For two circles $S_1=0$ and $S_2=0$ where the coefficients of $x^2$ are same in both the equations, the equation of this line is given by $S_1 - S_2 = 0$.

For more, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis)

Comment: The coefficients of $x^2$ **and** $y^2$... Under the hood, $C_1=C_2$ expresses the property of having equal power wrt the two circles.

Comment: In a circle, the coeff of x^2 and y^2 are always equal I guess @JeanMarie

Answer (score 1):

By choosing the *radical axis* $AB$ for a point on  $ R,$ so that $ RQ'=RS;$  even when $Q'RS'$ is not a straight line, even when circles are *non-intersecting.*

[image]